# parssing parameters POST

Tags: php, asp.net, web-services, http

I want to create a REST Web Service by using which I am able to get the result in the form of portal Morocco rail travel including train ticket prices.

```
url: http://www.oncf.ma/PrixEtReservation/Pages/BilletsNormaux.aspx
```

Basically I want to create a Web Service with php, but I can't found in http header names of this parameters to send request using Curl:

```
Gare départ 
Gare d'arrivée  
Confort
Type Réduction
Nombre d'adultes 
Nombre d'enfants   
Date départ 
Heure départ
```

Can anyone please kindly provide me help.

Comment: `i can't found in http header this paramters to send request using Curl` -- I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Could you explain?

Comment: I try to send request to server ohttp://www.oncf.ma/PrixEtReservation/Pages/BilletsNormaux.aspx using POST to get reponse, but i dont have paramters and i cant found this paramters in header of http

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `but i dont have paramters and i cant found this paramters in header of http`?

Comment: To send request to server with Curl i need some paramters name, but can't get name of parammters